# Codeigniter cannot access ODBC Microsoft Access on OSX

Tags: php, mysql, macos, codeigniter, ms-access

Im trying to solving this since 1 week ago.. 
On this case, i want to use CRUD with MS ACCESS Database (.mdb) on OSX Yosemite.

Everything is running well on My Windows, but when checkout my CI Project on Mac OSX Yosemite, my project show no error when i load database access.

When i use ODBC Manager on OSX, it said "Test Completed Successfully". But still show anything when i running those project :(

this is my sample code for database configuration

```
$db['dba']['hostname'] = 'attBackup';
$db['dba']['username'] = '';
$db['dba']['password'] = '';    
$db['dba']['database'] = 'attBackup';
$db['dba']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['dba']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['dba']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['dba']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['dba']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['dba']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['dba']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['dba']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['dba']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['dba']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['dba']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

anyone have some solution for this case?
thanks 
gbu

Comment: Try to use an IP address.

Comment: thx for advice, 
but i use Ms access for connection. not SQL Server..

Comment: The server will not be able to resolve the hostname. Try to use an IP or use a dsn string.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a DSN and changing to the following:

```
$db['access']['hostname'] = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\DB.mdb"; //dsn name
$db['access']['username'] = "";
$db['access']['password'] = "";
$db['access']['database'] = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\DB.mdb";
```

There's also a section in the CodeIgniter documentation that addresses connection strings:

The Documentation Of CI That addresses this is [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)

Hope may this help

If still having problem then Check

check read/write permissions etc